# Image view in layout android

Tags: android

I am trying to make a imageview in android but during the execution I find this e error in Resource id cannot be an empty string (at 'id' with value '@+id/').

Comment: You have an **id** with empty value, check your xml file (maybe your ImageView id).

Comment: At least paste some code, what you have tried so far. In java and xml

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/">

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to declare an ID

```
    <RelativeLayout 
      xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
      xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"; 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" 
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
      tools:context=".MainActivity" 

      android:id="@+id/ExampleID">  // Give your Id here..
```

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/"> i have problem in this line

Comment: Example ID like what ?

Comment: Just put one name to your id, or paste the whole XML file in the question please

Comment: good thanks Skizo its work now  i have error :Error:(40, 22) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/flesh').

Comment: code :<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Miralina travel tours"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="106dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="106dp"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false" />

Comment: That's because you don't have a src/drawable with flesh name, this is not of the TextView problem because you didn't assign a drawable, so just delete the `@drawable/flesh'`

Comment: int [] image = {R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2,R.drawable.image3}; create constant field R

Answer (score 0):

do it like this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSpeak"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/speak"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now" />
       </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Skizo after the performance when I click to change the image button is not changed

Comment: after the execution of the application when I click button to change the image is not changed